# Measuring real advertising effect: control group issue

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, marketing

**Background**:

The goal is to measure impact of advertising technique - retargeting. Retargeting is about showing related ads to prospects who add something to shopping cart but abandon it. We would be paying a fixed % of all sales that are made by visitors that are successfully retargeted.

The issue is that such program would cannibalize other marketing channels to some extent, i.e. some of those sales would have happened anyway. We would like to **place a cap on the payouts** to advertising company by measuring the real impact of their program.

**Our Approach**:

We are thinking or constantly splitting all website visitors into two groups:

- **Control Group** - will not be retargeted (some of them will come back through other channels)
- **Target Group** - will be a target of the retargeting program (some of the sales that are attributed to the program would have happened anyway - this is what it is all about)

I came up with this formula:

$$cap = (R_t - (R_c * \frac{C_t}{C_c})) * x$$

Where:

- $R_t$ - Target Group Revenue (last 30 days, e.g. \$100000)
- $R_c$ - Control Group Revenue (last 30 days, e.g. 20000)
- $C_t$ - Target Group Size ("seen" in last 30 days, e.g. 8000)
- $C_c$ - Control Group Size ("seen" in last 30 days, e.g. 2000)
- $x$ - Commission Rate (e.g. 10%)

We are simply calculating how many times the target group is larger than control group, multiplying the result with revenue from the control group. This way we get an approximate estimate of how much revenue we could have made from the **target** group if they were **not** retargeted. I guess this logic is clear enough.

**The Question**:

I have been teaching myself statistics for the last few hours but still do not clearly understand all the confidence interval, confidence level and other things like that.

I need to find out what % of all visitors to assign to the control group to have trustworthy data about which I could say something like this - "By paying out \$1000 we can be 99% sure that we are not overpaying and not underpaying by more than \$50".

I need to prove it by calculations which should be described in plain English as well.